# Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys, I need your help. What can be my problem why its giving me this Errror as mentioned in the Title?

Here is my code:

```
 if (!$connect){ 
        die("Failed to connect to the database: ".mysql_error()); 
    } 
$kies_bd = mysql_select_db("eraenz_db1",$connect); 
    if (!$kies_bd){ 
        die("failed to choose from BD: ".mysql_error()); 
    } 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ListNumber FROM residential");// or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error()); 
$result1 =  mysql_fetch_assoc($query) or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error()); 
echo $result1;
    if (mysql_num_rows($result1) >10){ 
        $difference = mysql_num_rows($result1) - 10; 
        $myQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM residential ORDER BY ListNumber LIMIT 10,". $difference) ;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Warning: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, resource given ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169146/php-warning-sort-expects-parameter-1-to-be-array-resource-given)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) function accept resource identifier

in your case it is `$query` Note that `$result1` is the fetched array and contain the data from database that should not be passed in this function.

```
mysql_num_rows($query)
```

And I would suggest you read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/) before asking quesions

Comment: Thanks, but why is my echo giving me an empty Array?

Comment: @Corrie: echo can not print Arrays,Objects you can print it using `print_r($result1)`

Comment: Thank you, you have been great help!