# PHP: Warning: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, resource given

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to arrange the array of table list with sort() function but i am getting same kind of warning.

```
<?php 
require_once("lib/connection.php"); 

$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM `st_db_1`");
 
sort($result);
foreach ($result as $result){
    echo $result ;
} 
?>
```

and the warning I am getting are:

> Warning: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, resource given in C:\wamp\www\Copy (4)       of st_db_1\test_2.php on line 9
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\Copy (4) of st_db_1\test_2.php on line 10

Comment: You need to [fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/function.msql-fetch-array.php) the result first. E.g. using `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result):`

Comment: you need to lookup on what `mysql_query` returns, as well as `mysql_fetch_assoc`. By the way you'll need to use `print_r` instead of `echo` to see the structure of.

Comment: As well in your foreach loop, you are overwriting the `$result` variable which is probably not what you want at all.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is pretty clear: `mysql_query` does not return an array with results from the query, but a resource. You need a function like `mysql_fetch_array()` to return the data you need (and on which you can perform a sort operation).

See the manual for the use of `mysql_query()` https://www.php.net/mysql_query

And maybe unrelated, but you can sort your results in MySQL right away by adding `ORDER BY <fieldname>` to your query.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not providing the most efficient code imaginable, but this should make it clear what's going on and solve your problem:

```
 $result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM `st_db_1`");

 $my_array_of_table_names = array();
 while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
     $my_array_of_table_names[] = $row[0];
 }
 sort($my_array_of_table_names);

 foreach ($my_array_of_table_names as $table_name){
     echo "$table_name\n";
 }
```

Comment: Yup, moved the sort to the right place.  That's what I get for not testing before posting.  Uh, will go test now to make sure I didn't just make it worse.

Comment: No problem, the main problem is that the person asking this question was not fetching the rows. And you showed this. Now we have almost the same answer. I gave you a point and might delete my answer later because they are too similar.

Answer (score 2):

The variable $result is only a resource of the type result. You need to fetch then the data from the result set with e.g. [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM `st_db_1`");
$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[] = $row["Tables_in_st_db_1"];
}
sort($array);
foreach ($array as $item) {
   echo $item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you aren't actually getting the data from the query.

`mysql_query()` doesn't give you a recordset.

What it does is query the database and returns a database resource which you can then use to get the data.

What you need is after calling `mysql_query()`, you then need to also call `mysql_fetch_array()` or similar. (there are a range of functions available, but that's probably the best one to use in this case). Then `sort()` the data from that, not `$result`.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says: it expects an array and you pass something else.

If you had checked the type of `$result` you would have seen that it is not an array, intead a resource.

Comment: i checked ,,its a array if table names but i am successfully able to fetch array of table using while loop